# Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found

Tags: boot, encryption, 18.04, lvm

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 Desktop enabling full disk encryption and with LVM. After the installation, every time I'm starting the machine, I see some messages appearing on the boot screen.

From the `/var/log/boot.log`, I have got the followings:

```
  Volume group "ubuntu-vg" not found
  Cannot process volume group ubuntu-vg
  Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...
  Found volume group "ubuntu-vg" using metadata type lvm2
  2 logical volume(s) in volume group "ubuntu-vg" now active
/dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-root: clean, 313479/31145984 files, 41462620/124578816 blocks
```

Is there anything wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After getting kernel update to **4.15.0-33-generic**, apparently, these messages are not getting displayed during startup.

Comment: The problem might be connected with `initramfs` like in [my case](https://askubuntu.com/a/1103132/250300). `initramfs` is updated during a kernel update.

Comment: This continues to be [initramfs-tools package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/initramfs-tools/+bug/1768230) bug in kernel update 4.15.0-76-generic