# Ubuntu looks for a removed volume group during boot

Tags: boot, server, lvm

I [cloned my Ubuntu Server to a virtual machine](https://askubuntu.com/questions/920669/converting-a-physical-linux-machine-to-use-in-vmware) on my laptop to do some tests. I adapted `/etc/fstab` and network configuration but I am unable to get rid of LVM. While the original server uses LVM, the clone has a single partition setup:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0   64G  0 disk
└─sda1   8:1    0   64G  0 part /
sr0     11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
```

However, this is still showing during boot:

```
Volume group "vp11-testsrv-ubuntu-vg" not found
Cannot process volume group vp11-testsrv-ubuntu-vg
```

[image: Volume group not found; Cannot process volume group]

<sup>(I am sorry to post a screenshot of text. Is there any file where I can find these boot messages? I cannot find them in `/var/log` and the output of `dmesg`.)</sup>

It’s probably just a warning and the boot continues successfully but I want to get rid of the LVM traces. How can I achieve this?

The commands `pvs`, `vgs`, `lvs` showed nothing and 
I even ran `sudo apt remove lvm2` without problems but the boot messages are still there.
I also removed `lvm` from `GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES` in `/etc/default/grub` and ran `sudo update-grub`.
I have only found traces of the server’s LVM in `/var/log` (old records from the original server) and the `archive` and `backup` subfolders of `/etc/lvm`.

This is my `/etc/fstab`. The commented items are related to the original server.

```sh
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
UUID=cbd35c50-81be-4e7f-a412-d1f4bed90c00    /                    ext3    errors=remount-ro 0  1
# /boot was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=fb5493ef-7c3b-4009-9765-47969fb83b68 /boot                              ext3 defaults  0  2
#/dev/mapper/vp11--testsrv--ubuntu--vg-swap_1 none                            swap sw        0  0
#/dev/mapper/vp11--testsrv--ubuntu--vg-vboxes /home/virtbox/VirtualBox\040VMs ext3 defaults  0  2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that the traces of LVM were stored in [`initramfs`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_ramdisk). I found the question [Can't find LVM root dropped back to initramfs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551446/cant-find-lvm-root-dropped-back-to-initramfs) and ran the mentioned command:

```
sudo update-initramfs -u -k all
```

Since that, the messages regarding LVM have no more been appearing during boot.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

On Debian-based systems before running `update-initramfs` command make sure that `cryptsetup-initramfs` package is installed. If not, install it first:

```
apt-get install -y cryptsetup-initramfs
```